# retrive date after 1.3 year from the given date in php

Tags: php, datetime

I am working on date and I am stuck at a point. How can I get the date after 1.2 or after 1.5 year from the given date?

My code is as follows:

```
$date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($from_date . ' +'.$valid_duration.' '.$day) );
```

where `$valid duration` can be number as 1, 2, 1.2, etc. and `$day` is year, months, days.

Comment: 1.2 year = 1 year 2 months?

Comment: now need to add  438.291  days on current date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the future date try this:

```
$StartingDate = date('Y-m-d');  // todays date as a timestamp

$newEndingDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($StartingDate)) . " + 1 year 2 months 5 days"));
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can define years/months/days with a decimal point.

But regardless, have you considered just using the timestamp?

86400 seconds in a day, so say you wanted to get date from one year in the future, you could use something like:

```
$thetime = time() + (365 * 86400);
$date = date("Y-m-d", $thetime);
```

Comment: But there aren't 86400 seconds in every day, not even close